# Unmarshall JsonNode changing data type

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class like:

```
Class myClass {
    @JsonProperty("status")
    boolean status;

    public boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public boolean setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public boolean setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = "free".equals(status);
    }
}
```

I would like to know who I can unmarshall using Jackson these JSON documents:

```
{
   "status" = true
}

{
   "status" = "free"
}
```

I thought by creating the two setters it will be more than enough but I think another directive is required.

Any help is more than welcome.

Edit: Partial solution

By setting JsonProperty in one of the setters it works for one case, but I want both at same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a thought. What about accepting an Object type instead!!?
Then you can do an instanceOf check and set accordingly.

```
public class MyClass {

    @JsonProperty("status")
    Object status;

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return Boolean.valueOf(status.toString());
    }

    public void setStatus(Object status) {
        if(status instanceof Boolean){
            this.status = status;
        }else if(status instanceof String){
            this.status = status.toString().equals("free");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyClass [status=" + status.toString() + "]";
    }

}
```

### Test

```
String jsonString_1 = "{ \"status\":true}";
String jsonString_2 = "{ \"status\":\"free\"}";

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

MyClass myObj_1 = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString_1.getBytes(), MyClass.class);
MyClass myObj_2 = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString_2.getBytes(), MyClass.class);

System.out.println(myObj_1);
System.out.println(myObj_2);
```

### Result

```
MyClass [status=true]
MyClass [status=true]
```

Comment: Nice!! I didn't realize playing with Object!!! Thanks. Would it support primitive data types?

Comment: Sure, you have used 'boolean' in your setStatus().